# Bootcamp, Removed Windows partition, why does it still ask for a disk at startup?

Tags: macos, boot, boot-camp, reboot

I removed a Windows 7 64bit, partition on my MacBook Pro. There are no partitions, except a single OS X partition left.

However, when I restart my computer, it automatically goes into a mode where it asks for me to insert a disk.

I can hold down the `option` key, I can select OS X and it boots fine.

**How do I get it to always boot into OS X and not ask for a windows startup disk?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OS X, open System Preferences, and in the System section, choose Startup Disk. Select the Mac OS X system on your HD (you might have to authenticate with your password by clicking the lock icon first.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the partition that used to exist is the one that the EFI is looking to boot from.  It had been "blessed".  Follow Chris' directions above (or below) to fix it.